# Call Java function with parameter Map<String, String> from c++ with std::map<std::string, std::string>

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

How can I call `Java` function which takes `Map<String, String>` as parameter from `C++` when I have `std::map<std::string, std::string>` in c++.
I know how to call Java function from c++ when parameters are simple types as int and so on but how to call for Map

```
t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID, params);
```

Is there any trick to achieve this ?

To use separated two `jobjectArrays of jstring` and glue by index to Map in Java function or is there more elegant solution ?

Comment: If the Java function modifies the map, you'll have to synchronize changes after the function returns.

Comment: If the Java function keeps a reference to the parameter, you might need to rethink things.

Comment: With a tool like JavaCPP, you could simply use the `std::map<std::string, std::string>` C++ object from Java, and do whatever you need from there. If you'd like more details, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If the Java function takes a `Map<String,String>`, you have to pass an object of that type. As you've noticed, a C++ `std::map` is not a Java Map. You can copy your `std::map<std::string,std::string>` into a newly constructed Java `Map<String,String>` before calling the Java function.

That's going to require creating a Java Map from C++ (e.g., a HashMap), and filling it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it. You have to construct `HashMap<String, String>` inside your code.

You will need something like this:

```
// Creating HashMap - we have to instantiate object of class HashMap
jclass hashMapClass = env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");

// Get the constructor of HashMap
jmethodID hashMapConstructorID = env->GetMethodID(hashMapClass, "<init>", "()V");

jobject hashMap = env->NewObject(hashMapClass, hashMapConstructorID);

// Get id of 'put' method
jmethodID putMethodID 
  = env->GetMethodID(
      hashMapClass, 
      "put", 
      "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

// For each pair inside 'map' I will call 'put' of Java based HashMap
for(auto const &pair: map) {
  jstring key   = env->NewStringUTF ( pair.first.c_str() );
  jstring value = env->NewStringUTF ( pair.second.c_str() );

  env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, putMethodID, key, value);
}
```

Once you have `HashMap` filled, you can call your method where you expect `HashMap` as a parameter.

You can find full sample code here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo061